# How do I upload ID, an username, and an image all to the database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I recently made a new table just for displaying the images and I was wondering how to upload them. Unfortunately, after some research I was still stuck on how to exactly perform this. So far the only thing I can do is upload the image name. I want to upload the id, username, and image name all in one query. I thought about using the `AND`, but that resulted into some errors.

```
<?php

$msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $target = "profiles/uploads/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
    $images = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_images (images) VALUES ('$images')";
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $msg = "Image Uploaded Successfully";
        header("Location: personal_profile.php?uploadsuccess");
    } else {
        $msg = "There Was A problem uploading image";
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your HTTP-POST look like?

Comment: Which id? where do you have the username? I'd suggest storing the user id with the image to know which images belong to which users. And I strongly suggest getting that ID from the logged in users session, as having that in the form let's anyone store images as any user (just change the form value for user id). When you have the values you need just search for mysql insert and you'll see how to do a query with multiple values

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with the technical name. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Do you mean this @JimL `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);`? I have that in the register form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your connection database is correct.

```
    $msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $target = "profiles/uploads/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {///when upload your file in directory insert yout patch file in directory
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
        $images = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $target_dir = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]" ."profiles/uploads/".$images;//your patch file for show in page website
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_images (images) VALUES ('$target_dir')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $msg = "Image Uploaded Successfully";
        header("Location: personal_profile.php?uploadsuccess");
    } else {
        $msg = "There Was A problem uploading image";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not showing up in the database when I upload it

Comment: if nothing save in your database even your root URL..you have problem in connection database.are you sure you do config right connection?? 
or in your table user you have only 2 column's id and images???

Comment: In my table I have id, username, and images. And on my other table I have username and other information. Yeah, I believe my db connection is correct. @pedramshabni

Comment: Also to add, it does save to my folders

Comment: when you use insert into you must enter all the values.for your table like this 
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_images (images,username) VALUES ('$target_dir','your_username')"; of course if your id in table  is auto increment

Comment: And do I have to identify the `$username` function?

Comment: yes sure.you must Specify Each photo is for which user.

Comment: Would I say `$username = $_SESSION['username']` or something like that?

Comment: yes.if you set $_SESSION['username'] .you can do it

Comment: Ok I see it in the database, but I do not see the username and the image has the full URL @pedramshabani

Comment: karen i don't know anything about your design table .but you say you have tow table .when you want to add image for user you must fetch username of other table.and use that for this code.

Comment: Ok gotcha. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

While you can store an image in the database it is better and general practice to store it on a directory and store the path to the image in the table

Comment: How do I do that? @MarceloClaure